# How to keep item from menu selected after clicking on it

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, selected

I have tried to create a small filter menu using Html, Css and Javascript.

I have the following issue: when I click on a different item of the menu except for the first, the white "pill" element goes on the selected one, but after the page loads, it returns to the first element - when an item is clicked, the page reloads and goes to that section.

This is the menu and the white pill element which is at the first item is the one that should remain on the selected items: the current behavior is that when I click on "today", for example, it moves over it, but when the page loads and I see the page for "today", the white pill returns to the first element.
[image]

The code is here:

```
 <head>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>

 <div id="wrapper-filter">
 <ul id="filter-bar">
     <span class="pill"></span>
        <li class="filter-option option-1 active" data-target="option-1"><a href="{{ route(request()->route()->getName(), 'last-day') }}" class="nav-item nav-link {{ $match_date == $third_day_date? 'active': '' }}">{{ $third_day_date }}</a></li>
        <li class="filter-option option-2" data-target="option-2"><a href="{{ route(request()->route()->getName(), 'yesterday') }}" class="nav-item nav-link {{ $match_date == $second_day_date? 'active': '' }}">Yesterday</a></li>
        <li class="filter-option option-3" data-target="option-3"><a href="{{ route(request()->route()->getName(), 'today') }}" class="nav-item nav-link {{ $match_date == $today_date? 'active': '' }}">Today</a></li>
        <li class="filter-option option-4" data-target="option-4"><a href="{{ route(request()->route()->getName(), 'tomorrow') }}" class="nav-item nav-link {{ $match_date == $tomorrow_date? 'active': '' }}">Tomorrow</a></li>

      </ul>



                   <script>
                $(document).ready( function() {

                $("#filter-bar li").click(function(){
                    $("#filter-bar li").removeClass("active");
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                    $("#filter-bar").removeClass().addClass($(this).attr("data-target"));

                });

            })
            </script>
            </div>
```

```
<style>

#filter-bar {
     width: 100%; 
     margin:0; 
     padding:0; 
     height:auto; 
     display:inline-flex;
}

#wrapper-filter {
     background-color:#484747; 
     width: 100%; 
     height:auto; 
     margin:30px auto; 
     border-radius: 30px; 
     box-sizing: border-box;
}

#filter-bar li {
     width: 100%;
     background-color: transparent; 
     text-align: center; 
     list-style-type: none;
     z-index:10; 
     cursor: pointer; 
     font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif; 
     font-weight: 100; 
     font-size: 18px;
     line-height:36px;
}

.pill {
     position: absolute; 
     width:25%; 
     height: 50px; 
     background-color: #fff; 
     border-radius: 30px; 
     color: #444; 
     z-index:10; 
     border: 5px solid #eee; 
     box-sizing: border-box; 
}

.filter-option {
     transition: color 500ms;
}

#filter-bar.option-1 .pill {
     margin-left: 0%; 
     transition: margin-left 200ms ease;
}

#filter-bar.option-2 .pill {
      margin-left: 24.5%; 
      transition: margin-left 200ms ease;
}

#filter-bar.option-3 .pill {
       margin-left: 48.8%; 
       transition: margin-left 200ms ease;
}

#filter-bar.option-4 .pill {
        margin-left: 72.5%; 
        transition: margin-left 200ms ease;
}

.option-1.active{
    color:#484747; transition: color 200ms;
}   

.option-2.active{
    color:#484747; transition: color 200ms;
}   

.option-3.active{
    color:#484747; transition: color 200ms;
}   .

.option-4.active {
    color:#484747; transition: color 200ms; }

.nav-item {
    margin: 0 1px;
    position: relative;
}

.nav-item .nav-link {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.nav-item::before {
    position: absolute;
    width:25%; 
    height: 50px; 
    background-color: #fff; 
    border-radius: 30px; 
    color: #444; 
    z-index:10; 
    border: 5px solid #eee; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top;
    transform-origin: top;
    transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease;
    transition: transform .3s ease;
    transition: transform .3s ease, -webkit-transform .3s ease;
}

</style>
```

What can I do in order to make the white pill element remain on the clicked item of the menu?
I think the items that might needs a change are the ones from the end of the css, ".nav-item::before"...but I am not sure. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not redirecting the URL.
A solution is to create tabs of sort. [This](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_full_page_tabs.asp) fairly simplifies the explanation so check it out once. It shows how to create full page tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You are using < a > tags which are links.  When you click on them the link address will load.  You can prevent default behavior as shown, but what are you trying to do?

```js
                $(document).ready( function() {

                $("#filter-bar li").click(function(){
                 event.preventDefault();
                   $("#filter-bar li").removeClass("active");
                    console.log(this);
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                    $("#filter-bar").removeClass().addClass($(this).attr("data-target"));

                });

            })
```

```css
 

#filter-bar {
     width: 100%; 
     margin:0; 
     padding:0; 
     height:auto; 
     display:inline-flex;
}

#wrapper-filter {
     background-color:#484747; 
     width: 100%; 
     height:auto; 
     margin:30px auto; 
     border-radius: 30px; 
     box-sizing: border-box;
}

#filter-bar li {
     width: 100%;
     background-color: transparent; 
     text-align: center; 
     list-style-type: none;
     z-index:10; 
     cursor: pointer; 
     font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif; 
     font-weight: 100; 
     font-size: 18px;
     line-height:36px;
}

.pill {
     position: absolute; 
     width:25%; 
     height: 50px; 
     background-color: #fff; 
     border-radius: 30px; 
     color: #444; 
     z-index:10; 
     border: 5px solid #eee; 
     box-sizing: border-box; 
}

.filter-option {
     transition: color 500ms;
}

#filter-bar.option-1 .pill {
     margin-left: 0%; 
     transition: margin-left 200ms ease;
}

#filter-bar.option-2 .pill {
      margin-left: 24.5%; 
      transition: margin-left 200ms ease;
}

#filter-bar.option-3 .pill {
       margin-left: 48.8%; 
       transition: margin-left 200ms ease;
}

#filter-bar.option-4 .pill {
        margin-left: 72.5%; 
        transition: margin-left 200ms ease;
}

.option-1.active{
    color:#484747; transition: color 200ms;
}   

.option-2.active{
    color:#484747; transition: color 200ms;
}   

.option-3.active{
    color:#484747; transition: color 200ms;
}   .

.option-4.active {
    color:#484747; transition: color 200ms; }

.nav-item {
    margin: 0 1px;
    position: relative;
}

.nav-item .nav-link {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.nav-item::before {
    position: absolute;
    width:25%; 
    height: 50px; 
    background-color: #fff; 
    border-radius: 30px; 
    color: #444; 
    z-index:10; 
    border: 5px solid #eee; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top;
    transform-origin: top;
    transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease;
    transition: transform .3s ease;
    transition: transform .3s ease, -webkit-transform .3s ease;
}
```

```html
 <head>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>

 <div id="wrapper-filter">
 <ul id="filter-bar">
     <span class="pill"></span>
        <li class="filter-option option-1 active" data-target="option-1"><a href="{{ route(request()->route()->getName(), 'last-day') }}" class="nav-item nav-link {{ $match_date == $third_day_date? 'active': '' }}">{{ $third_day_date }}</a></li>
        <li class="filter-option option-2" data-target="option-2"><a href="{{ route(request()->route()->getName(), 'yesterday') }}" class="nav-item nav-link {{ $match_date == $second_day_date? 'active': '' }}">Yesterday</a></li>
        <li class="filter-option option-3" data-target="option-3"><a href="{{ route(request()->route()->getName(), 'today') }}" class="nav-item nav-link {{ $match_date == $today_date? 'active': '' }}">Today</a></li>
        <li class="filter-option option-4" data-target="option-4"><a href="{{ route(request()->route()->getName(), 'tomorrow') }}" class="nav-item nav-link {{ $match_date == $tomorrow_date? 'active': '' }}">Tomorrow</a></li>

      </ul>
      
      </div>
```

Comment: I want the link to load as expected, but the white pill to go on the selected item of the menu. So, after adding your changes, the white pill moves as expected and it remains there, but the page does not load. How can I make the page load also ?

Comment: So, if I run your code snippet, the behavior is right ( the white pill moves as expected). But I also need my page to go to <page-link>/tomorrow or <page-link>/today

Comment: can you help me with a suggestion ? I am new in front-end development and I do not know how to make both these things happen :( I need my scenario combined with yours in order to be right

Comment: when the new page loads it comes from the server.  You need to take the information from javascript and pass it to your controller.  From there, you need to update the page. Or, do yopu just want to move to a different place on the current page?

Comment: so, the code that I put was loading fine, when I clicked on "today" it went to <page-link>/today because of the routes that are created. I need this behavior added to the "white pill" movement accordingly to the item clicked. So, if I click on "today" I want to white pill to remain there, because my code does this: I click on "today". the white pill goes to "today". but after the page loads, it comes back to the first item

Comment: what you did is the thing that I want from the white pill, but the page does not load anymore. I need what I have, with the page load, plus what you provided me: the white pill remaining where I click on

Comment: are you loading a different page?

Comment: yes, this is the website that I try to modify: https://www.findyourbets.com/ I am trying to change the way date is shown

Comment: you can see here what happens if you click on "today". "tomorrow" etc

Comment: so I went to your site.  Very Nice!.  But it doesn't look like anything really changes when you click on the tabs

Comment: what are you using on the backend? php? python?

Comment: well, nothing changes because there are no tennis matches right now :D take a look at the link of the page, that one changes :D for backend, php

Comment: so, in php you need to update the css for the linked page